# Pointer to constructor overload?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have a bunch of legacy code that looks like:

```
#define MAKE_FOO_FNS(fooname) \
fooname* makeFoo_ ## fooname ## A(A arg) { \
  return new fooname(arg); \
} \
fooname* makeFoo_ ## fooname ## B(B arg) { \
  return new fooname(arg); \
} \
// ... repeated many more times
```

so that later in the code we can say:

```
MAKE_FOO_FNS(FooType1);
MAKE_FOO_FNS(FooType2);
```

and then have access to function pointers with the types:

```
 FooType1* (*)(A);
 FooType1* (*)(B);
 FooType2* (*)(A);
 FooType2* (*)(B);
```

I know that I can replace `MAKE_FOO_FNS` with templates:

```
template<typename FooType>
FooType* makeFooA(A arg) {
  return new FooType(arg);
}
// .. etc ..
```

so that we can get the function pointer from `&MakeFooA<FooType1>`, `&MakeFooA<FooType2>`, etc, without any macro hackery.

But this still seems like unnecessary boilerplate --- is there a (C++11) way to get a function pointer directly to "invoking operator `new` of `FooType1` with the constructor that takes an `A`" without writing all of these wrapper functions?

Comment: Yes, writing a 4-line function was such terrible boilerplate... The fact of the matter is that a lot of people don't need a pointer to a function that returns a newly allocated object of an arbitrary type. Some people do, but you can write that yourself, as you have done.

Comment: @Nicol: there are about 20 in the real code.

Comment: C++ does not allow you to obtain the address of a constructor. So you have to wrap the `new` in a function, then you can get the address of that function.  Using a template is the cleanest solution, but I would suggest a two-parameter template so you can specify the `arg` typename as well, then you don't need separate `A` and `B` functions. `template<typename FooType, typename ArgType> FooType* makeFoo(ArgType arg) { return new FooType(arg); }`, `&MakeFoo<FooType1, A>`, `&MakeFoo<FooType1, B>`, etc.

Comment: Why are there 20 lines? You can use variadic templates to pass along any number of parameter types.

Comment: What do you need such a pointer for? What problem does `makeFoo<X>(a)` solve that writing `new X(a)` doesn't?

Comment: @Barry: maybe the functions are being used in a class factory that registers function pointers at runtime.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question: Where do you get "function pointers" here? Are you omitting some typedefs? Also: Why don't use perfect-forwarding to construct arbitrary objects? In that case one templated function would be sufficient.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm asking because it's an important part of the question. Maybe the function pointers aren't necessary at all. Maybe there's an external API that requires them, etc.

Comment: @Barry: the *why* is not relevant to the question as it is asked, only the *how* is important. We have to answer the question as asked. If you want to query the OP for the *why* in order to offer alternative solutions, that is a different matter, but that is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Remy -- yes, that's exactly the situation (a class factory)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might merge all the makeFooA<>(), makeFooB<>(), etc. functions into a single generic template:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T* make_ptr(Args&&... args)
{
    return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This has the advantage that passing multiple parameters is now possible (either by value or by reference) and the drawback that you need to specify full signature when taking the address, i.e., &make_ptr.

Note that, if you have boost, you don't need to implement it yourself: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/functional/factory/doc/html/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use a lambda. A capture-less lambda can be implicitly converted to a function pointer:

```
X*(*p)(A) = [](A arg){ return new X(arg); };
```

If you want even less typing and more safety, you could also just take a pointer to the right specialization of `std::make_unique`:

```
auto p2 = std::make_unique<X, A>;
```